# How can I close a popup in Azure Maps

Tags: azure-maps, azuremapscontrol

I am using AzureMapsControl.Components but I'm 99% certain this is an Azure Maps issue.

I am displaying a popup with the close button. However, clicking on the close button does not close it. Is there something I need to set to make the close work? [Looking at this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/AzureMapsCodeSamples/blob/main/Samples/Popups/Show%20clustered%20points%20in%20popup/Show%20clustered%20points%20in%20popup.html#L126), there does not appear to be.

There is no click event for the popup and the close event is not fired clicking on the X so I don't know what needs to be done to enable closing.

I am creating a popup as:

```
PinTooltip = new Popup(new PopupOptions
{
    // Position is set in OnPinMove()
    Position = new Position(MapCenter!.X, MapCenter.Y),
    PixelOffset = new Pixel(0, -20),
    CloseButton = true,
    OpenOnAdd = false,
});

await mapArgs.Map.AddPopupAsync(PinTooltip);
```

and then I display it as:

```
Action<PopupOptions> tooManyEntities = options =>
{
    options.Content = $"<div style=\"padding:10px;color:black\">There are {numPoints} events at this location<br/>which is too large to display in a list.<br/>Please revise your search terms to reduce<br/>the number of events returned at this location.</div>";
    options.Position = ((AtlasMapPoint)cluster.Geometry).Coordinates;
    options.CloseButton = true;
};
Task.Run(async () => await PinTooltip!.SetOptionsAsync(tooManyEntities));
Task.Run(async () => await PinTooltip!.OpenAsync());
```

Note that I set `OpenOnAdd = false` and I display it with `PinTooltip!.OpenAsync()`

[image]

Comment: I'm only familiar with creating popups via javascript. Does browser developer tools indicate any javascript messages?

Comment: @Nick.Mc Good question but no. The F12 Console just has a couple of setup messages. Nothing when I click. Nothing to the ILogger either. And the actual javascript running for this is buried in altas.min.js so diving in to that would be killer. thanks

Comment: I guess next step is create a minimum repro and raise an issue in GitHub (or if your minimum repro works, incrementally add functionality till you find the part causing the issue0

Comment: @Nick.Mc Unfortunately I think you're right. I was hoping someone looked at it and said "you forgot to set...". thanks for looking at it.

Comment: Try using the browser developer tools an inspecting the popup elements. It's possible some custom CSS or other element is preventing the X button from receiving click events. For example, if the popup-container or popup-content-container CSS class was overridden with pointer-events: none; no mouse events will work within the popup.

Comment: @rbrundritt I suspect you're right. But I've spent the last 2 hours going through that with no luck. It's not just the click is being ignored, the cursor remains a hand when over the popup. So it's somehow telling the cursor that the popup doesn't exist. I've got my UX person trying to figure it out. thanks

Comment: If the cursor is remaining a hand that is a good indication that the popup either doesn't have pointer events enabled or there is something floating above it blocking the events. If you open up any of the Azure Maps samples in the browser, and run the following code in the console, you will get the same behavior `var t = document.createElement('style');t.appendChild(document.createTextNode('.popup-container{pointer-events: none !important;}'));document.head.appendChild(t)`